# What is causing a slow Laravel 8 website?

Tags: laravel, debugging

I have migrated one website from Laravel 5.7 to Laravel 8.
On localhost, everything seems to work fine, unfortunately on my webserver sometimes pages get loaded very slot. It can take more than 20+ seconds to load the contact page. On that page, there is just one MySQL query.

[image]

The Timeline debugbar is showing just the time to load the page, but nothing more.
I am posting here all my packages, maybe some on them is causing this?

```json
"require": {
      "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
      "albertcht/invisible-recaptcha": "^1.9",
      "arcanedev/log-viewer": "8.x",
      "darkghosthunter/laraguard": "dev-master",
      "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
      "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
      "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
      "intervention/image": "^2.5",
      "jamesmills/laravel-timezone": "^1.9",
      "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
      "lab404/laravel-impersonate": "^1.6",
      "langleyfoxall/laravel-nist-password-rules": "^4.1",
      "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
      "laravel/socialite": "^5.0",
      "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
      "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
      "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",
      "livewire/livewire": "^2.0",
      "mcamara/laravel-localization": "^1.6",
      "predis/predis": "^1.1",
      "rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables": "^0.3",
      "rappasoft/lockout": "^3.0",
      "romanzipp/laravel-twitch": "^4.0",
      "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.14",
      "spatie/laravel-html": "^2.28",
      "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.6",
      "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.11",
      "stichoza/google-translate-php": "^4.1",
      "tabuna/breadcrumbs": "^2.2",
      "thujohn/twitter": "^2.3"
  },
  "require-dev": {
      "roave/security-advisories": "dev-master",
      "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
      "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.6",
      "codedungeon/phpunit-result-printer": "^0.29",
      "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
      "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.16",
      "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
      "laravel/sail": "^0.0.5",
      "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
      "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
      "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
  }
```

I don't have any clue how to solve this problem. Will appreciate every tip or tool on how to analyze my pages.

Comment: Does your application attempt to pull data from an service (external API, database) with a long timeout. If this generates an error, and the error is being swallowed without reporting, this may cause a lengthy timeout for you.

Comment: You need to time what is happening in your code. Also look at your database indexes. Are they setup correctly? Try running the query inside phpMyadmin for example and see if the query self is the problem.

Comment: Thank you guys, but the problem is not the database. There are indexes and everything. Sometimes the pages are loading normally, but sometimes very slow and I cannot find out why. On localhost everything is fine.